# Are there any .NET/ JAVA free or opensource SPAM detectors that yield good results?

Tags: java, .net, api, spam-prevention, spam

I am looking for a .NET/ JAVA free or opensource SPAM detectors accesible via an API that yield good results. I would consider paying for a good service that accomplishes this as well, but ideally, I would like to go open source.
Does any one have any good experiences with any or recommendations?

Ideally, I would get the text/markup to a message in memory, I would call a method from this API, and it would return a bool or likelyhood of SPAM.

A quick google search yielded some results, but users with experience to share are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi I am Hazza Ammkan and I run spam company in Nigeria I see you have problem with spam - I have an interesting business proposition for you. It require only you send $1000 and then you will receive spam softwear within 5 days. Please to meet you and hope we can do business.

Comment: have you searched serverfault?  This seems more IT-related than dev-related to me.

Comment: Any particular reason it has to be written in .NET or Java? If you have mentioned just one of those I wouldn't have asked, but if you are able to pick the platform, why not a Perl solution (http://spamassassin.apache.org/) ?

Comment: RE: DDAviesBRackett

I thought about this, but in the end I opted with SO since I'm looking for an API -- To me serverfault is more for settings and ready to go products. That's just me though, you may be correct :-)

Comment: RE: Mostly because I'm comfortable with those and lazy, but you are right. I will checkout spamassasin, that looks interesting.

Comment: @Matt, you mark a post community wiki by editing it and checking the community wiki box.  I don't think you need to mark this question CW though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the [Akismet .NET 2.0 Api](http://www.codeplex.com/AkismetApi) on CodePlex.

Here's an example from the CodePlex page:

```
// Verify key
Akismet api = new Akismet("key", "http://url.com", "Test/1.0");
if (!api.VerifyKey()) throw new Exception("Key could not be verified.");

// Create comment object for testing
AkismetComment comment = new AkismetComment();
comment.Blog = "http://joel.net";
comment.UserIp = "147.202.45.202";
comment.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)";
comment.CommentContent = "<a href=\"http://someone.finderinn.com\">find someone</a>";
comment.CommentType = "comment";
comment.CommentAuthor = "someone";
comment.CommentAuthorEmail = "backthismailtojerry@fastmail.fm";
comment.CommentAuthorUrl = "http://someone.finderrin.com";

// Test comment against akismet's service
bool isSpam = api.COmmentCheck(comment);
```

Akismet rocks.

-Charles

Comment: Akismet ROCKS.  I came here to mention it, but i was beaten to the punch.  +1!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to implement this is to setup a Google domain account for your email and let Google deal with your spam. Then you can either access that account using regular pop3 or imap api or simply forward all email to your real account.